# How to eliminate val repetition in this Scala assign/test/throw sequence

Tags: scala, boilerplate

This code throws an exception when properties.keySet contains keys that are not present in EXPECTED_IMPORT_KEYS. The val is referenced three times in the code,

```
val unexpectedKeys = properties.keySet -- EXPECTED_IMPORT_KEYS
if (unexpectedKeys.nonEmpty) {
   throw new UnexpectedKeysException(unexpectedKeys)
}
```

Is there some more elegant way to achieve this in Scala? I am thinking in particular of the repeated val references. Can those repetitions be eliminated?

It might help to know that the unexpectedKeys val is not required after the code completes.

The improvement I am looking for is a reduction from three in the number of times the val occurs. It is not necessary to have a val, that's just my initial formulation.

Answer (score 4):

If you need this often, just define a little helper method:

```
def emptyOption[A, CC <: Iterable[A]](coll: B with collection.IterableLike[A, CC]) =
  if (coll.isEmpty) None else Some(coll)
```

Then use it like this:

```
scala> emptyOption(Set[Int]()) foreach (coll => throw new RuntimeException(coll.toString))

scala> emptyOption(Set[Int](1)) foreach (coll => throw new RuntimeException(coll.toString))
java.lang.RuntimeException: Set(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
(properties.keySet -- EXPECTED_IMPORT_KEY) match {
  case residual if residual.nonEmpty => throw new UnexpectedKeysException(residual)
  case _ =>
}
```

Comment: "match" did occur to me but I was unable to improve on the example provided here where residual is mentioned three times.

Comment: Once to name it, once to check if it's empty, and once to throw it ... i doubt you'll do much better.

Comment: I'd say improvement is at least the fact that there is no unnecessary `val` (unexpectedKeys) defined . Value `residual` is defined only in scope of match.